# JQuery animation (Transit) with fixed position not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, position

lately I've been playing around with this JQuery plugin called Transit by Rico Sta. Cruz (http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit), I'm making a menu that have 'fixed' position so when the page scrolls the menu will also scroll. After i add the 'fixed' position the animation of the Transit plugin won't work. Here is the code for the css of the scrolling menu

```
#sbuttoncont
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:20%;
    float:right;
    padding-left: 7%;
    position:fixed;
}
#menu
{
}

#menu ul
{
    text-align: right;
}

#menu li
{
    display: block;
    position:relative;
}

#menu li a, #menu li span
{
    display: block;
    background: #FFC661;
    margin-top: 1em;
    padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
    letter-spacing: 0.20em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFF;
    opacity:1;
    width:80%;
}

#menu li:hover a
{
}

#menu li.active a, #menu li.active span
{
}

#menu .current_page_item a
{
    background: #D99827;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

As you can see i add the 'postion:fixed;' in the '#sbutton' and the '#menu' is inside it, here is the HTML code

```
<div id="sbuttoncont">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#" accesskey="1" title="">Home</a></li>
            <li class="sbt"><a href="index2.html" accesskey="2" title="">Competitions</a></li>
            <li class="sbt"><a href="index3.html" accesskey="3" title="">Scores</a></li>
            <li class="sbt"><a href="index4.html" accesskey="3" title="">Merchandise</a></li>
            <li class="sbt"><a href="index5.html" accesskey="4" title="">Partners</a></li>
            <li class="sbt"><a href="index6.html" accesskey="5" title="">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the JQuery script for the animation

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".sbt").mouseover(function() {
            $(this).transition({x: '-40px'}, 350);
        });
        $(".sbt").mouseout(function() {
            $(this).transition({x: '0px'}, 350);
        });
        $(".current_page_item").mouseover(function() {
            $(this).transition({x: '-40px'}, 350);
        });
        $(".current_page_item").mouseout(function() {
            $(this).transition({x: '0px'}, 350);
        });
    });
</script>
```

And what i want to achieve is to make the menu scrolling along with the page and working animation while in mouseover the menu button will move to the left 40 px, thank you so much for your help. Please let me know if you need the full HTML

Not to be confused, this is the Full HTML document(using the .animate)
    
    
    
    
    http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    
    html, body
    {
        height: 100%;
    }

```
body
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #2DBCF6 url(images/BACKGROUND%20ACEX.jpg) fixed;
    font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #000000;
    width:100%;
    z-index:999;
}


h1, h2, h3
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

p, ol, ul
{
    margin-top: 0;
}

ol, ul
{
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

p
{
    line-height: 180%;
}

strong
{
}

a
{
    color: #ff3e37;
}

a:hover
{
}
.container
{
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 1000px;
}
.image
{
    display: inline-block;
}

.image img
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.image-full
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 3em 0;
}

.image-left
{
    float: left;
    margin: 0 2em 2em 0;
}

.image-centered
{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}

.image-centered img
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
}
ul.style1
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
    color: #6c6c6c
}

ul.style1 li
{
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    padding: 2.80em 0em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    border-color:  rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

ul.style1 li:first-child
{
    padding-top: 0;
    border-top: none;
}

ul.style1 .image-left
{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

ul.style1 h3
{
    padding: 1.2em 0em 1em 0em;
    letter-spacing: 0.10em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #454445;
}

ul.style1 a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #525252;
}

ul.style1 a:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #525252;
}

ul.style2
{
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 1em;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.style2 li
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    border-color:  rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    padding: 0.80em 0;
}

ul.style2 li:first-child
{
    border-top: none;
    padding-top: 0;
}       
.title
{
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}

.title h2
{
    font-size: 2.8em;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}

.title .byline
{
    letter-spacing: 0.15em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: #6F6F6F;
}
#header-wrapper
{
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0em 0em;
}

#header
{
}
#logo
{
    padding: 0 0 0 3%;
    text-align: center;
    float:left;
    width:70%;
}

#logo h1
{
    display: inline;
    margin-bottom: 0.50em;
    padding: 0.20em 1em;
    background: #36C;
    font-size: 3.5em;
}

#logo a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}

#logo span
{
    display: block;
    margin-top:1em;
    letter-spacing: 0.10em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: #000000;
    padding-top:0.3em;
}

#logo span a
{
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
#sbuttoncont
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:20%;
    float:right;
    padding-left: 7%;
    position:fixed;
}
#menu
{
}

#menu ul
{
    text-align: right;
}

#menu li
{
    display: block;
    position:relative;
}

#menu li a, #menu li span
{
    display: block;
    background: #FFC661;
    margin-top: 1em;
    padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
    letter-spacing: 0.20em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFF;
    opacity:1;
    width:80%;
}

#menu li:hover a
{
}

#menu li.active a, #menu li.active span
{
}

#menu .current_page_item a
{
    background: #D99827;
    color: #FFF;
}
#copyright
{
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0.3em 0.5em 0.3em 0.5em;
    background: #333333 url(images/DialogueBox1.png) center;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
}

#copyright p
{
    letter-spacing: 0.20em;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 0.65em;
    color: #303030;
}

#copyright a
{
    text-decoration: overline underline;
    color: #323232;
}
#post
{
    overflow: hidden;
    width:69%;
    padding: 1em 0.3em 1em 0.3em;
    background: #333333 url(images/DialogueBox1.png) center;
    margin: 1em 0 1em 3%;
}
#post h2
{
    color: #303030;
    text-align:center;
}
#post img
{
    display:block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
#post p
{
    letter-spacing: 0.20em;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 0.65em;
    color: #303030;
}
</style>
<title>ACEX2014</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header-wrapper">
<div id="header">
<div id="logo">
<img src="images/logoacextransparent.png" alt="ACEX2014">
<span>Companionship in diversity for a peaceful living</span>
</div>
<div id="sbuttoncont">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#" accesskey="1" title="">Home</a></li>
            <li class="sbt"><a href="index2.html" accesskey="2" title="">Competitions</a></li>
            <li class="sbt"><a href="index3.html" accesskey="3" title="">Scores</a></li>
            <li class="sbt"><a href="index4.html" accesskey="3" title="">Merchandise</a></li>
            <li class="sbt"><a href="index5.html" accesskey="4" title="">Partners</a></li>
            <li class="sbt"><a href="index6.html" accesskey="5" title="">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="post">
<h2>About ACEX 2014</h2>
<p>ACEX adalah event tahunan SMP Labschool Kebayoran yang berupa rangkaian kompetisi. ACEX adalah kependekan dari 'Art, Culture and Sport Exhibition'. Acara ini mencakup kegiatan seni, kebudayaan dan olahraga seperti namanya.</p>
<p>ACEX tahun ini mengusung tema 'Arcade Games' dan panitia pelaksananya merupakan murid angkatan 12 SMP Labschool Kebayoran.</p>
<h2>Countdown To Opening</h2>
<img src="images/TBU.png" alt="To Be Unlocked!">
<h2>Trailer</h2>
<img src="images/TBU.png" alt="To Be Unlocked!">
</div>
<div id="copyright">
    <p>COPYRIGHT (C) <a href="http://acex2014.blogspot.com" rel="nofollow">ACEX2014.BLOGSPOT.COM</a>. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED | DESIGN BY <a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">@WirasutaTude</a></p>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
  $(".sbt").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).animate({left: '-40px'}, 350);
  });
  $(".sbt").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).animate({left: '0px'}, 350);
  });
  $(".current_page_item").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).animate({left: '-40px'}, 350);
  });
  $(".current_page_item").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).animate({left: '0px'}, 350);
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: I'm new to these JQuery Stuff, so your help is really appreciated

Comment: what isn't working right now? Everything seems fine

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you load the JQuery (`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>`) above your script?

Comment: i forget to paste it above, but i already include it and still not working

Comment: @WirasT "Not working" is not and never will be a problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the animate function of jQuery, works in a similar way and is more supported:

```
    $(function() {
      $(".sbt").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).animate({left: '-40px'}, 350);
      });
      $(".sbt").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).animate({left: '0px'}, 350);
      });
      $(".current_page_item").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).animate({left: '-40px'}, 350);
      });
      $(".current_page_item").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).animate({left: '0px'}, 350);
      });
    });
```

I have also created a jsfiddle.net page, so you can try the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/sgruenwald/WL4T7/1/

Comment: Still not working :/ i've added the full HTML above, maybe there's something wrong with other elements?